Azure APIM multiple identity providers for same API
my API is accessed by external clients and some clients uses Microsoft Account token and some clients uses Entra token.  in case of Entra token, i have to verify client application id. How can i achieve this in APIM. do i have to use validate-jwt and read issuer and the have choose block to add validate-azure-ad-token policy? or there is any other way to achieve it.

Yes, you need to use validate-jwt policy

Both validate-azure-ad-token and validate-jwt policies can be used to validate tokens. However, while validate-jwt can be used to validate any JWT, validate-azure-ad-token has been specifically designed to validate tokens issued by Microsoft Entra ID. I've been using validate-jwt to validate Microsoft Entra ID tokens as well.
A decoded token might look like this:
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "M1KfKFJ_inXbwWc23xYxw1sUHH9",
  "kid": "M1KfKFJ_inXbwWc23xYxw1sUHH9"
}.{
  "aud": "api://some-audience",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/0b76e9a6-d632-3f1d-aef8-afb226e9aee4/",
  "iat": 1716212172,
  "nbf": 1716212172,
  "exp": 1716216072,
  "aio": "F2NgYLDW+UiyzeKV/aaZG2cU38q5AgB=",
  "appid": "dce16fdb-321f-3e57-0cf8-3ac67b6fc3af",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/0b76e9a6-d632-3f1d-aef8-afb226e9aee4/",
  "oid": "6fa5d814-f3fb-3294-01f6-8991201d9b12",
  "rh": "0.ARAApel2-zHmHE--97-yJumu4-WkLOVE_l1Psy18JLqgVeGXAAA.",
  "roles": [
    "Some.Role1",
    "Some.Role2",
    "Some.Role3"
  ],
  "sub": "6fa5d814-d3fb-3293-01f4-6991201d9b12",
  "tid": "0b76e9a6-d632-3f1d-aef8-afb226e9aee4",
  "uti": "nC8NHk3npEV_ADeIujsoAB",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]

In this case, you might choose to use the validate-jwt policy like this:
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Request is not authorized." require-expiration-time="false" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/0b76e9a6-d632-3f1d-aef8-afb226e9aee4/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <audiences>
        <audience>api://some-audience</audience>
    </audiences>
    <issuers>
        <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/0b76e9a6-d632-3f1d-aef8-afb226e9aee4/</issuer>
    </issuers>
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="appid" match="any">
            <value>dce16fdb-321f-3e57-0cf8-3ac67b6fc3af</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>

This way, you are validating  the issuer (the security token service), the audience (the intended recipient of the token), and the application ID. If you  skip the app ID validation and validate only the audience, then any token generated for this audience and for any other app ID will pass the validation.
Personally, I prefer having a role-based access control instead of hardcoding the app ID in the policy. In this case, the policy would look like this, and validate the role of the app:
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Request is not authorized." require-expiration-time="false" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/0b76e9a6-d632-3f1d-aef8-afb226e9aee4/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <audiences>
        <audience>api://some-audience</audience>
    </audiences>
    <issuers>
        <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/0b76e9a6-d632-3f1d-aef8-afb226e9aee4/</issuer>
    </issuers>
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="roles" match="any">
            <value>Some.Role2</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>


If you want to verify Entra client Id, then you can use validate-azure-ad-token policy in APIM which only requires tenant Id and client Id.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-azure-ad-token tenant-id="Azure AD tenant ID">
            <client-application-ids>
                <application-id>Azure AD application/client ID</application-id>
            </client-application-ids>
        </validate-azure-ad-token>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

You need to pass the bearer token for the same tenant id and client id in request header to test the validation.


Trace-

You can also use validate-jwt policy to validate issuer along with client id.
Please note- while generating token use https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_Id}/oauth2/v2.0/token Url and scope as api://{client_Id}/.default.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_Id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>Application Id{api://{client_Id}}</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_Id}/</issuer>
            </issuers>
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud" match="all">
                    <value>Application Id{api://{client_Id}}</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>


Among these two policies, you can choose any one as per your requirement.

You are not verifying the app id in validate-jwt here.

@10p when we will validate the jwt token eventually application/client id will get verified. As per the MS doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy in validate-jwt policy there is no explicit attribute present to pass app id alike validate-azure-ad-token

I've tested it in the past - you can use same openid-config url, same issuer, same audience, but different app id/secret (as you can have multiple app ids) - and the token would still be generated and accepted using the setup you've just suggested. Not a great approach from security perspective. I'll probably create a new answer with additional details.

@10p I have modified my answer

Audience and app ID are different things. It would make sense to test it.

@10p Yes Indeed but you can check the both using jwt.io. I have tested with this configuration and it worked for me. Generally the value of scope used to generate token would be same as audience

I added my answer to clarify my point
